# token required after fresh install of InfluxDB 2.6.1 in GKE

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

Trying to do a fresh install/deploy of gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/influxdb2:latest (2.6.1) into a GKE cluster. Using the CLI (influx setup) to configure the initital user, pwd and token. All runs fine, no errors and I can confirm user, pwd and token is set using the CLI on the container.

But when doing port forwarding and open the admin UI for influx I can't login. Get a "can't login in" error message and log says,

msg=Unauthorized log_id=0hh8usRW000 error="token required"

Any suggestions?